# Repeating fire-simulation continuously without keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, fluid-simulation, fire

I did alot of desperate research, but couldn't find anything helpful; here is my problem: I rigged my v8-engine, assigned some materials, but now it's time to simulate the internal combustion.

I am indeed able to set up a particle system with domain, fire-simulation and bake it (all that stuff), but here comes the difficulty: Obviously the explosion should only happen at the right time - when the piston reaches its top position every second time.

Due to the fact that I have a controller bone to move the whole engine, I **do not want to keyframe** the fire-simulation. With the bone I'm able to control the speed of the engine, which then I can keyframe for my animation.
Hence, is there any possibility to bind the particle system, respectively the whole simulation, e.g. to the position of the piston, so that it only goes off when the piston is in the right location or rotation driver stuff (because then I can easily control the speed of the engine, since the **explosion is not binded to any frames**)?

I hope that any one know how to solve my little issue here :/)
If something is still unclear, just let me know please.

EDIT: GN may work, but for me my results won't look so photo-realistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you "just" have a particle fire (and not a "real" fire simulation with domain) you could use geometry nodes to do that, because it is totally procedural. Geometry nodes as it is today can already do everything what particles can do (AFAIK). By a driver you can input the location information to your GN node tree and driver your simulation. Hope it helps.

Comment: So I tried around a lot, but it doesn't seem to look that good. My first setup is a particle system with an adaptive domain and a material assigned to it (basically this here: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxfctMsd0Ck&t=1079s)). With gn I cant get it to look that photo-realistic. Is there any other way to work around?

Comment: @Philipp: sorry that my answer wasn't clear: i meant, if you don't (!) use a domain. Getting a realistic fire simulation with GN is possible - but you need a lot of experience for that. Tbh i would use fire textures and use that e.g. with GN. This should be repeatable easily. So you just animate some images with fire textures.

Comment: Is there a method using a domain at all, or ist this just not possible?

Comment: i personally think that with Blender "everything" is possible - if you have enough time and will - the question is, whether you wanna invest so much time and will ;) as i wrote, i think the much easier and quicker solution for you is rendering your fire animation, then use animation nodes or geometry nodes to "just" show these rendered image sequences (which by the way do ALL the great artists out there because it is fast, efficient and in most of the cases you won't even see it except you watch it in slow motion). I just watched a tutorial video of a very...

Comment: ...talented Blender user who said, he never used simulations (fire/smoke/cloth) because (for him) it is to slow, to unstable, not predictable and very memory consuming. And i could really understand that.

Comment: always remember, even if you do the "best" fire simulation ever - if you are making a movie out of it, even with moving camera, it is "just" displayed on a 2d display, so no one can see whether it is 2d if you are "just" using 2D as well.....  ;) only if you have to use VR/AR this would be worse of course, because that's the only "real" 3D device right now.